# AngularJS ng-repeat does not update the $ctrl in UI

Tags: angularjs, pug

I'm updating my model in `applyType` method but the items are not reflecting in the UI.

Here is what I'm doing

### My model is : model.js

```
export default function model(
  $scope,
) {

...

model.$name = 'editModelController';
model.$templateUrl = {
  sku: templateUrl,
};
```

### My component:

### index.js

```
export default function addItemDialog(app) {
  app.component('addItemDialog', {
    controller,
    bindings: {
      resource: '<',
      ngIf: '=',
    },
  });
}
```

### addItemDialog.js

```
export default function addItem(
  $q,
  $mdDialog,
) {
  this.$onInit = () => {
    ...
    this.applyType();
  };
}

this.applyType = () => {
    this.units = this.loadMoreUnits();
};

addItem.$inject = [
  '$q',
  '$mdDialog',
];
```

### addItemDialog.pug

```
md-select.select(
    ng-model="$ctrl.unit",
    placeholder="Unit",
    name="unit",
)
    md-option.select__option(
      ng-repeat="unit in $ctrl.units",
      value="{{ unit.unit }}",
    )
      .select__option-content
        span.select__option-text {{ unit.description }}
```

I'm console logging `this.units` its updated there but not updated in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Answering as I do not have enough rep to comment.

Have you tried accessing the units object like this:
`unit in units` rather than using `$ctrl`?

I have seen some cases where you can access the fields from the controller directly without having to refer to the controller explicitly.

Regards,

M